# Spock: can an interaction defined in setup() be replaced in a test case?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I'm struggling to understand something about Spock interactions in a Groovy unit test.

I have the following types:

```
public interface Bar {
  public String getMessage();
}

public class Foo {
  private Bar bar;
  public void setBar(Bar bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }
  public String getMessage() {
    return bar.getMessage();
  }
}
```

and I then wrote the following Groovy/Spock test:

```
class FooSpec extends Specification {

  private Bar bar;
  private Foo foo;

  def setup() {
    bar = Mock(Bar) { getMessage() >> "hello" }
    foo = new Foo()
    foo.bar = bar
  }

  def "say hello"() {
    expect:
    foo.message.equals("hello")
  }

  def "say goodbye"() {
    setup:
    bar.getMessage() >> "goodbye"

    expect:
    foo.message.equals("goodbye")
  }
}
```

The code creates a mock `Bar` instance in the setup, initializes `Bar.getMessage()` to return `hello`, and assigns this to a new `Foo` instance.

The first test verifies that `foo.getMessage()` is equal to `hello`.

The second test tries to modify the `bar` mock so that it's `getMessage` method returns `goodbye`. We then expect that `foo.getMessage()` (which delegates to `bar.getMessage()`) would then return `goodbye`. However the test fails as follows:

*FooSpec:say goodbye:26 Condition not satisfied*

because `foo.message` is still equal to `hello`.

I also tried the following:

```
def "say goodbye"() {
  when:
  bar.getMessage() >> "goodbye"

  then:
  foo.message.equals("goodbye")
}
```

and:

```
def "say goodbye"() {
  when:
  no_op()

  then:
  bar.getMessage() >> "goodbye"
  foo.message.equals("goodbye")
}
```

But both failed with the same *hello does not equal goodbye* message.

I'm probably still thinking in Mockito mode, and assume that an interaction is the equivalent of a `when(...).thenReturn(...)` expression, and that later interactions would override earlier interactions.

Is there a simple way using Spock to declare an interaction in a `setup` method, then override that interaction in a test case? Or do I need to remove the `setup()` method and basically add a `setup:` block to each test case?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

That's a tricky one. As stated in the [docs](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html#_where_to_declare_interactions), interactions declared in a then-block have precedence over interactions declared earlier. However, interactions declared in a then-block are scoped to the previous when-block. (This allows to have multiple when-then pairs.) Hence your last try doesn't work, but the following will:

```
def setup() {
    bar.message >> "hello"
}

def "say goodbye"() {
    when:
    def msg = foo.message

    then:
    bar.message >> "goodbye"
    msg == "goodbye"
}
```

I agree that it would be good for interactions declared in test methods to always override interactions declared in setup methods. Anyway, a good alternative to overriding interactions is for each test method to call a helper method that sets up the expected interactions for that test method.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm going to eschew using a `setup()` method and change my test methods to initialize their state directly (this is also motivated by the fact that I often use a `where:` block in my test methods, and found to my surprise that the `setup()` method was called after the `where:` block). I *think* I can understand your example above, but it's not intuitive (it still looks like setup code in the `then:` block to me).

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser, what Spock version have you used in this example? We've tried this and a lot of other variations with Spock 1.0, but it didn't work.

Comment: @JohnQCitizen I often use this tactic when I want to both assert that a service method has been called a certain number of times, as well as controlling what data is returned. I think in this example, I would put it in a `given:` block.

Comment: Answer is correct, to override behavior you have to use then: block - even given: block does not work (which is bad imo)