# Override mock behavior defined in setup-method (groovy spock)

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

Is it possible to define a behavior of a mock in the *setup()* method and then override it in some test methods? Something like this:

```
SomeMockableObject smo = Mock()

def setup() {
  smo.returnSomething() >> "foo"
}

def "test method that expects smo to return 'foo'"() {
  // some test code
}

def "test method that expects smo to return 'bar'"() {
  given:
  smo.returnSomething() >> "bar"

  // some test code
}
```

I have tried this, but *smo.returnSomething()* always returns "foo". Am I doing something wrong or is it just not possible to do this?

Comment: sorry for bothering you, just found my anwser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22215929/spock-can-an-interaction-defined-in-setup-be-replaced-in-a-test-case?rq=1